# I am trying to update user's detail using python flask but prompt "peewee.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint"

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, peewee

I am now being prompt

> peewee.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

whenever I am trying to update user details such as from username "testing" to "testing2".

[image]

Here is the user.py

```
class User(UserMixin, BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True, null=False)
    email = CharField(unique=True, null=False)
    password = CharField(unique=False, null=False)
```

Here is the views.py

```
@users_blueprint.route('/profile', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def edit_profile():
    # check whether both email and username has been taken, if not update the specific profile
    form = UpdateDetailsForm()

    if check_password_hash(current_user.password, form.data['password']):
        if current_user.username != form.data['username']:
            updated_user = User.update(username=form.data['username']).where(User == current_user)
            updated_user.execute()
        if current_user.email != form.data['email']:
            updated_user = User.update(email=form.data['email']).where(User == current_user)
            updated_user.execute()
        if form.data['password'] != form.data['new_password']:
            # updated_user = User.update(password=generate_password_hash(new_password)).where(User == current_user)
            updated_user = User.update(password=generate_password_hash(form.data['new_password'])).where(User == current_user)
            updated_user.execute()
        flash("Profile successfully updated", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('users.view_profile'))
    else:
        flash("Kindly ensure that the initial password matches", "danger")
        return redirect(url_for('users.view_profile'))
    return redirect(url_for('users.view_profile'))
```

Here is the profile.html

```
{% extends "_layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('users.edit_profile') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        {% for field in form if field.name != "csrf_token" %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {% if field.name != "btn" %}
            {{ field.label(class="form-control-label form-control-lg") }}
            {% endif %}
            {% if field.name != "btn" %}
                {% if field.name == "username" %}
                    {{ field(class="form-control", value=current_user.username) }}
                {% elif field.name == "email" %}
                    {{ field(class="form-control", value=current_user.email) }}
                {% elif field.name == "password" %}
                    {{ field(class="form-control", value=current_user.password) }}
                {% elif field.name == "new_password" %}
                    {{ field(class="form-control", value=current_user.password) }}
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            {{ field(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            {% endif %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
            {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the forms.py

```
class UpdateDetailsForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        'Username',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Length(min=5, max=20)
        ]
    )
    email = StringField(
        'Email',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Email()
        ]
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        'Password',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Length(min=8, max=20)
        ]
    )
    new_password = PasswordField(
        'New Password',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
            Length(min=8, max=20)
        ]
    )
    btn = SubmitField('Update Profile')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the where clause:

```
.where(User.id == current_user.id)
```

Comment: I can't believe that worked.... =.= any explanations why? Like I thought as long as the comparison of object would be clear enough, never expected it require a "value" instead of "object" comparison. Anyways, upvoted.